# How to increment column chart automatic X-Axis labels by 1 when the number of columns is highly variable?

Tags: c#, charts, axis

I have a column chart and the X-Axis dynamic labeling unfortunately starts at 0 rather than 1. So if I have 4 data points I'm trying to plot, it will start plotting them and label them 0, 1, 2, 3 rather than 1, 2, 3, 4.

My picture should make it more clear.

I have tried tinkering with the code but I don't know how to change the interval labelling while still keeping it dynamic (because sometimes I'll have only 3 or 4 points, sometimes almost 200).

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = false;
```

But that doesn't fix it.

I should add that setting the minimum AxisX value to 0 simply hides the first value, so if you had 4 values, it would hide the first and show the next 3 still mislabeled.

I basically want to set:

`chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Label = (Double.Parse(chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Label) + 1).ToString();`

[image]

Comment: What are the X-Values of your datapoints? Valid numbers??

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe it was so simple. In my for loop for adding my datapoints, I changed my x-value to x+1. Such an easy solution - thanks!